Windows server 22 Powershell Get-EventLog Not Showing "Account Name:" in CSV Export
In the event viewer the field name that I am looking for in the CSV export is "Account Name:" however, this field does not display in the export but does display if the "Result in PowerShell" script is run.
Result in PowerShell:
Get-EventLog -LogName Security| Select-Object -Property * | Select -first 10

CSV Export Script:
Get-EventLog -LogName Security | Select-Object -Property * | Export-Csv -Path C:\Export.csv

What I would like to achieve is pulling a report of user activity on the file share.

Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

@JosefZ I tried my best to make it as simple as possible and simplified the code to work in all scenarios. Of course there will be filters on Event ID and defined columns to lighten the load of the query.

I believe "account name" is buried in the message property, unless you want to manipulate the properties property or call toXml() on the object. Actually I'm thinking of get-winevent.

Apply calculated properties:

Several PowerShell cmdlets transform, group, or process input objects
into output objects using parameters that allow the addition of new
properties to those output objects. You can use these parameters to
generate new, calculated properties on output objects based on the
values of input objects. The calculated property is defined by a
hashtable containing key-value pairs that specify the name of the new
property, an expression to calculate the value, and optional
formatting information.

In particular, you can use calculated properties to add additional members to the objects output with the Select-Object cmdlet, e.g. as follows:
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator
Get-EventLog -LogName Security | 
    Select-Object -Property @{ 
            name = 'Account Name';    # or 'AccountName' with no space
            expr = {($_.Message -split [System.Environment]::NewLine |
                        Select-String 'Account Name:' -SimpleMatch |
                        Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line
                     ).Split( ':').Trim()[-1]
                   } }, * |
    Select-Object -First 2                # optional to reduce output

However, some output fields (e.g. Data or ReplacementStrings) Export-Csv shows as System.Byte[], System.String[], or even System.Object[] etc. See this article :Avoiding System.Object[] (or Similar Output) when using Export-Csv…

Get-winevent and xml example. It doesn't call it 'account name' in the xml, but the data is the same.
$a = get-winevent @{logname = 'security'} -MaxEvents 1
[xml]$xml = $a.toxml()
$xml.event.eventdata.data

Name              #text
----              -----
TargetUserName    admin
TargetDomainName  COMP
TargetSid         S-2-3-22-3961843718-1576926590-2901110931-1101
SubjectUserSid    S-2-3-22-3961843718-1576926590-2901110931-1101
SubjectUserName   admin
SubjectDomainName COMP
SubjectLogonId    0xc6ff76
CallerProcessId   0x173c
CallerProcessName C:\Windows\explorer.exe

